# Unable to build module in typescript

Tags: visual-studio-2013, typescript

I am newbie in Typescript.
I have created a new project in Typescripts in Visual Studio 2013.
But whenever I try to build my project I am facing an error:
**'Error 1 Cannot compile modules unless the '--module' flag is provided'.**

Please suggest where I am doing wrong.

Comment: you must select a module manager to compile to. there should be an option for it in the project's properties in visual studio. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I was using require js in my project and that needs AMD option to be enabled from project->properties->typescript build -> Module System = AMD.

After checking the Radio Button my problem got solved.